# FindRoot + NDSolve + List?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, evaluation

I've noticed that `FindRoot` fails when its argument involves a component of a list, to which a substitution rule from `NDSolve` has been applied. Below is a minimal example.

Is it possible to force FindRoot to understand the second syntax below?

```
Clear["Global`*"]

rules[y_?NumericQ] := Flatten@NDSolve[{
    u'[x] + u[x]^2 == 1,
    u[1] == y}, u, {x, 0, 1}]

(*works*)

f[y_] := {u[1/2] /. rules[y], 1};

FindRoot[f[y][[1]], {y, 0}]


(*fails*)

f[y_] := {u[1/2], 1} /. rules[y];

FindRoot[f[y][[1]], {y, 0}]
```

Comment: `f[y][[1]]` produces a syntax error "ReplaceAll::reps: {rules[y]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing." and `u[1/2] /. rules[y]`.

Comment: FWIW: I managed to solve my issue by applying Thread to the latter example. Mathematica still produces lots of warnings, however, and I clearly don’t understand what’s going on under the hood.

Comment: The easiest fix is to add a `Evaluated -> False` to `FindRoot`. This has been discussed quite a bit in this site, you can search `Evaluated` here to find more related posts. (BTW, +1 for writing a clean example :) )